# JDBC and SQL+ return different results on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

Query in question:

```
select count(*) from test m where m.IND_1 is not null AND m.IND_2 is null
```

This query will return 1 using SQL+, and 0 through a JDBC template. I expect 1 to be the correct result.
All the usual suspects have been checked (for instance, is DB the correct one, same user is used and so on).

Does anyone have any similar experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I sometimes forget to "COMMIT" something from SQL editors with AutoCommit disabled. Then in this editor session I got my changes, but in other sessions they were not visible.

Try to check it from other session, even from SQL+ running on other machine.